# Search and replace part of URL via apache htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to rewrite URLS like:

```
http://post.local/web/bundles/silverkixcms/elFinder/elfinder.html?CKEditor=silverkix_cmsbundle_pagetype_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

to

```
http://post.local/bundles/silverkixcms/elFinder/elfinder.html?CKEditor=silverkix_cmsbundle_pagetype_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

Means the part "web/" should be replaced by ""(or remove it), but I have problems to build a rewrite rule for my .htaccess which cover that.

*Note: mod_rewrite is on (RewriteEngine on)*

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^web/bundles/(.*) bundles/$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^web/bundles/(.*) /bundles/$1 [R]
```

The above will remove `web/` from the url so

```
http://post.local/web/bundles/silverkixcms/elFinder/elfinder.html?CKEditor=silverkix_cmsbundle_pagetype_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

will become

```
http://post.local/bundles/silverkixcms/elFinder/elfinder.html?CKEditor=silverkix_cmsbundle_pagetype_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```